# How to interate an array with navigation menu buttons (first, previous, next, last)

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, loops

Well, one more question. Since I started learning javascript short time ago, I am almost obsessed trying new things! Here it goes:

Let's say that I have an array of strings and I want to iterate on it with a navigation menu with the buttons FIRST, PREVIOUS, NEXT, LAST.

Look at this code:

```
var thearray = ["article1", "article2", "article3"];

var thebody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var divcontainer = document.createElement("div");
var divpage = document.createElement("div");

function generatepage(article) {
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    var name = document.createTextNode(thearray[article]);
    paragraph.appendChild(name);
    divpage.appendChild(paragraph);
}

divcontainer.appendChild(divpage);
thebody.appendChild(divcontainer);


generatepage(0); // that would be for the first article
```

I also figured out that `generatepage(thearray.length -1)`would be the call for the last article, so I have solved two buttons (before generating new content I would erase it with `innerHTML`but what I cannot think about how to do are the PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons...

Do you have any suggestion about how should I get started to make working PREVIOUS and NEXT?

I attach a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ASyA9/)

Thank you so much for any advice!

Comment: None of the code works right now, but I would suggest storing the current page as a variable, updating it at the end of every call to generatepage, then calling generatepage(currentPage-1) and generatepage(currentPage+1) for your previous and next buttons, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the active page in a variable outside the function:

```
var page = 0;
```

Then you don’t need to bring any page into `generatepage()`:

```
function generatepage() {
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    var name = document.createTextNode(thearray[page]);
    paragraph.appendChild(name);
    divpage.appendChild(paragraph);
}
```

Now you can control the page from outside the function:

```
var next = function() {
    if ( page < page.length-1 ) { page++; }
}

var prev = function() {
    if ( page ) { page--; }
}
```

So to show the first page:

```
page = 0;
generatepage()
```

And the next:

```
next();
generatepage()
```

etc.... There are other ways too of course but this might give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction. I am about to have a fully functional exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a variable outside the scope of the function to memorize the current article
when you add Eventlisteners to the buttons you can call the next and previous item

but you should somehow replace the content of the div with the next one instead of appending it (i don't know a thing about manipulating dom elements)

you could try something like this:

```
var thearray = ["article1", "article2", "article3"];

var thebody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var divcontainer = document.createElement("div");
var divpage = document.createElement("div");
var currentarticle
function generatepage(article) {
    if(thearray[article]) {
    currentarticle = article
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    var name = document.createTextNode(thearray[article]);
    paragraph.appendChild(name);
    divpage.innerHTML= paragraph.innerHTML
}else {
    return false
    }
}

divcontainer.appendChild(divpage);
thebody.appendChild(divcontainer);


generatepage(0); // that would be for the first article




document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click",function() {
    generatepage(currentarticle + 1)
        });
            document.getElementById("previous").addEventListener("click",function() {
    generatepage(currentarticle - 1)
});
document.getElementById("last").addEventListener("click",function() {
    generatepage(thearray.length - 1)
});

document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click",function() {
    generatepage(0)
});
​
```

heres the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSTdP/)